# What phrase and adverb is it correct and natural to use instead of "so-so" when you want to say that you can do something either badly nor very well?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What phrase and adverb is it correct and natural to use instead of *so-so* when you want to say that you can do something either badly nor very well? Can I say any of the following?

> I am averege at math.
>
> I can swim adequately.
>
> I can swim neither well nor badly.

Comment: Depends which country you are using them in. For example, in the UK, "adequate" will tend to indicate superior performance to how it will be taken in the USA. But all of them are grammatically OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with

I'm average at math

I'm ok at swimming (but not great)

The last example sounds a bit weird (though it'd be understood). Neither/nor is usually quite formal. I tend to use neither/nor if I'm discussing an issue with someone or writing an article.